# Polynomial expansion of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Given $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers.

I want to request anyone who might know any formulas for expanding this following expression.
$$ |A-B|^{2n}$$
where $n$ is an integer.

The one that I commonly used for an order of $2$, i.e. $n=1$ is
$$ |A-B|^{2}= (A-B)(A-B)^*$$
where the $[.]^*$ means the Hermitian adjoint.

So I want to see if I can increase the order from $n=1$ to $n=\{2,3,4,5...\}$
Is there such rule? Maybe like a Pascal triangle theorem and/or Binomial property?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specifically for $2n$, you can use what you already stated above: $|A - B|^{2n} = (|A - B|^2)^n = ((A - B)(A - B)^*)^n = (A - B)^n(A - B)^{* n}$. If you have $2n + 1$, then this obviously becomes $|A - B|(A - B)^n(A - B)^{*n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|A-B\right|^{2n}
&=&
\left|(A-B)^n\right|^2
\\
&=&
\left|\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkA^k(-B)^{n-k}\right|^2
\\
&=&
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkA^k(-B)^{n-k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkA^{*k}(-B^*)^{n-k}\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 1):

What about $|A-B|^{2n}=(|A-B|^2)^n=\left((A-B)(A-B)^* \right)^n$?